# What is the IIS7 default keepalive time?

Tags: iis, iis-7, http, timeout, keepalive

What is the IIS7 default time for HTTP keepAlive?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The default connection timeout in IIS7 is 2 minutes.  Click on your web site in IIS Mgr, click Advanced Settings, and expand Connection Limits.  The Connection Timeout (Seconds) setting is what governs this.  If IIS doesn't receive activity on a connection for this duration then it will time the connection out.  This is regardless of whether or not the connection was requested as a keep-alive.  You will, of course, have to have keep-alives enabled for this to be a "keep-alive timeout".  Keep-alive is enabled by default in IIS.

You can also set it for the site in the applicationHost.config file using the `<limits>` and the `connectionTimeout` attribute.

```
<limits connectionTimeout="00:02:00" />
```

This will set the timeout value to 2 minutes.

Answer (score 8):

HTTP KeepAlive is a true/false switch. If HTTP Keepalive is true, it will use the "Connection Timeout" setting (default 120 seconds)

Answer (score 3):

Also you can use this option in your web.config

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" />
</system.web>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e1f13641%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: +1. By the way, the link you have there is for .Net Framework 3 which doesn't actually support an int for that attribute. I think you meant this link: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/e1f13641(v=vs.100)